# Add link to redirect to an external link in the Rich text editor

Tags: sxa

I have a case where there is a URL that is commonly used across the system and I need to add it in a common place in the tree and reference it from Rich Text.

So I tried the below:

- added the Link in Links node under Data node in content tree
- In the RTE, I added link to this link item in rich text

But when browsing it is not redirecting to the Link stored in this link item, it redirect to error page that this item has no layout.

Is there a way to reference the URL added in this link item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are talking about a Links node in the Data node I am assuming you are using SXA...

In that case, you could create a `redirect` item in your content tree (redirect is one of the ootb SXA options). When you link to that item, you should be redirected to whatever you have set in the redirection url in that redirect item.

The "Link" item you are using is actually a datasource for the Link component. Datasource items do not have layouts, so it is normal that you get this error.

Comment: I tried to create redirect item in tree and then add link to it in rich text but it redirect to the same page not to the external link

Comment: Just tried this on my environment and works perfectly. Added a redirect item in my content tree, filled in the "Redirection URL" field using the "Insert external link". Published. Added a link to this item in a RT field and works like a charm.

Comment: When trying it in publish mode it is working fine